# Running python script within a shell script: files don't save

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am very new to shell scripting, so I'm still figuring things out. Here is my problem:

I have a python .py executable file which creates multiple files and saves them to a directory. I need to run that file in a shell script. For some reason, the shell script executes the python script but no new files appear in my directory. When I just run the .py file, everything works fine

Here's what my shell script looks like:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    cd /home/usr/directory
    python myfile.py
```

Within my python script, the files that are saved are pickled object instances. So every one of them looks something like this:

```
    f = file('/home/usr/anotherdirectory/myfile.p','w')
    pickle.dump(myObject,f)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Stupid question, does `myfile.py` reside in `/home/usr/directory`? I know the level of stupidity on this one, just making sure. Also there should be no space between `#!` and `/bin/bash` :) And if you think you need the bash script for running this as a cron or a part of a installation process, just add `#!/usr/bin/python` to the top of your script and `chmod +x myfile.py` and you can execute it just like it would be a bash-script :)

Comment: myfile.py resides in the directory. The files that it creates are actually supposed to be saved to another directory. And my bad on the space, I don't have it in my script, just accidentally put it here. And the reason I need to put it in a bash script is because I need to submit it as a batch job so it has to be in a shell script format.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
f = file('/home/usr/directory/myfile.p','w')
```

Should be:

```
f = open('/home/usr/directory/myfile.p','wb+')
```

For best practices it should be done like this:

```
with open('/home/usr/directory/myfile.p','wb+') as fs:
    pickle.dump(myObject, fs)
```

Comment: `wb+` just means you open it in read+write binary form. How would this solve anything? Edit: noticed that it sad `file(` and not `open(` now, that would solve it yes.

Comment: @Torxed: He also changed `file` to `open`.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for the `file` function states:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file)

> When opening a file, it’s preferable to use [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) instead of invoking this constructor directly.

Problems like this may be one of the reasons why.  Try changing

```
f = file('/home/usr/directory/myfile.p','w')
```

to

```
f = open('/home/usr/directory/myfile.p','w')
```